# JasperReports counter variable always incrementing

Tags: variables, jasper-reports, report, ireport, counter

This should be a simple question on *JasperReports*. I'm trying to do a simple counter over the whole report that should increment based on a condition. However, whatever I try, it seems like the counter variable is always being incremented, regardless of the variable expression. My variable's definition properties are below:

*Class*: ***Integer***
*Calculation*: ***Count***
*Reset type*: ***Report***
*Increment type*: ***None***
*Variable Expression*: ***`$F{on_target}.doubleValue() >= 0.0`***
*Initial Value*: ***`Integer.valueOf(0)`***

I have a total of 23 rows in the data set, and based on the criteria, the counter should eventually equal 18. I have the variable outputting in the *Summary* band, with ***Evaluation Time*** to **Now**. However, regardless of the evaluation time, and even setting the ***Variable Expression*** to ***`Boolean.valueOf(true == false)`***, the variable's value always ends up as 23.

What simple little thing am I forgetting?

Answer (score 4):

I think I've got it. This makes vaguely no sense, but... (mind you, this is my first time working with Jasper Variables, so it was trial and error).

The Variable Expression isn't quite a Boolean, where a counter type variable isn't incremented if the expression is false, like you'd think. The variable is incremented if there is *any* value evaluated in the expression. Thus, for me, what ended up working is below:

`$F{on_target} >= 0 ? 1 : null`

Note the usage of null if the expression should be false.

It makes vague, twisted sense. But is in no way intuitive. Oh well, so it goes...

**or in other words:**

When you are using the *Calculation:Count* function of a Jasper-defined Variable you want the *Variable Expression*  to:

- resolve to ***non-null*** value to ***increment*** the counter
- resolve to a ***null*** value if you do ***not want to increment*** the counter

That's why the test listed above works

Comment: The COUNT function counts all non-Null values, both zeros and ones.  So any boolean would be counted.  This is similar to how the SQL COUNT function works.  So it makes sense that you need to return a NULL to not count a row.  Another way you could have done it would be to SUM the boolean values.  That way you would not need to return a NULL for a false.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the setting the variable expression to:

```
$F{on_target} >= 0 ? 1 : null
```

Try also setting the initialValueExpression of the variable to 0.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$F{on_target} >= 0 ? 1 : BigDecimal.ZERO
```

No initial variable value necessary.